# Can't find the Blank activity with fragment in android studio (3.3.2)

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

So I just started with Android studio and i am following the Android NanoDegree from Udacity and in one of the lessons i am supposed to create a Blank activity with fragment which does not exist any more i understand that the Empty activity is the same as the Blank activity  i have  searched and all i could find was old questions and the answer was to choose an empty activity then check the add fragment option  but i can't find the fragment option at all (See Image).

[image]

Can any one tell me what i should do to match the required activity from the lesson ... it has MainActivity.java and fragment_main.xml and activitymain.xml  and a place holder fragment in the mainactivity.java file

Comment: "Use a fragment" option is given while creating  "Basic" Activity

Comment: Yes it is but i am supposed to use an empty activity not a basic one

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, if you right click on your project in the project view, under New ->  Fragment -> Fragment (blank).

I tried to add a screenshot but I'm not allowed yet.